# Does Django have a method of storage like HTML5's localStorage or sessionStorage?

Tags: django, storage

Does Django have a method of storage like HTML5's localStorage or sessionStorage?

I want to use the Django/Django-Rest-Framework as the backend of my project.

but whether the Django has a convenient storage method to server my project? if in the HTML5 there are localStorage and sessionStorage, which is very useful.

---

**EDIT**

I want to use a simple method to store my temporary data, such as, if there is a requirement to share the data.

such as I have 3 providers (a_provider, b_provider, c_provider), they can process a origin_data.

in a function,

```
def process_data():

    a_provider(get_data())  # process a 
    b_provider(get_data())  # process b
    c_provider(get_data())  # process c
```

the `get_data()` can get the shared data.

rather than every process to return the processed data as param to pass into other provider.

Comment: This is a bit confused. The point of local storage is that it stores things in the browser. But Django is a server side framework so you can store things in the database.

Comment: Or whether there is some way like store the data in a `json file`, or other files, then we can get it by parse the file.

Comment: Yes if you like. But you didn't explain why you don't want to store things in the database.

Comment: @DanielRoseman See my edit, bro.

Comment: Is this data per-user?

Comment: yes, sure.  so if use the file to store, there should use a hashed username as the key?

Answer (score 0):

There are some 'Offline Solutions' you can check out [here](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/offline/)
However, If you are trying to completely run in local-storage Django probably isn't your choice. Some new development on this particular topic is being explored by the awesome team at [BeeWare](https://pybee.org/project/).

Hope this helps.